# Does the coordinate vectors(Vi)s spans R^n , if S in a set of a n dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, dimensional-analysis

Let $S = \{v_1,v_2,\dots ,v_r\}$ be a nonempty set of vectors in an $n$- dimensional vector space $V$.

Prove that if the vectors in $S$ span $V$, then the coordinate vectors $(v_1)S, (v_2)S,\ldots, (v_r)S$ span $R_n$, and conversely.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please describe where you are in the body of your question so that it is better-received. (Also, `dimensional-analysis` is not an applicable tag.)

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).